# creating a dynamic view in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a webgrid via this code

```
@grid.GetHtml(
                        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column(header: "Link", style: "labelcolumn", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit Item", "EditQueue", new { id = item.QueueID})),
                        grid.Column("Description", "Description"),
                        grid.Column("QueueDate", "QueueDate"),
                        grid.Column("Note", "Note"),
                        grid.Column("Status", "Status"),
                        grid.Column("LastUpdated", "LastUpdated")
                            )
                    )
```

I created a test case with ID 1.  I then click the link in the first column.  I get a 404 error because I haven't created a page for this at */Home/EditQueue/1*

However I obviously don't want to create a page for each number.  What is the best practice to create a page that just displays the ID I passed into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an action method which accepts the `id` as parameter, in your HomeController

```
public ActionResult EditQueue(int id)
{
    //Get the details of queue using id and return a view.
    return View();
}
```

You probably want to show the data to edit. so get the data using the id and return that.

```
public ActionResult EditQueue(int id)
{
    //Get the details of queue using id and return a view.
    Queue queue=repositary.GetQueueFromID(id);
    return View(queue);
}
```

Assuming `repositary.GetQueueFromID` method will return a `Queue` class object and your View (`Edit.cshtml`) is strongly typed to that.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your method with a parameter you are passing in the controller..

Comment: that gets called in the grid?

Comment: @Badmiral:..No, not in the grid, yuo will be redirected to the edit Item page in the same window